# How to remove _id when I print fields using printjson()?

Tags: javascript, json, mongodb, mongojs

```
db.events.find().forEach(function(doc)
{
    var iso_date = new Date(doc.starts_at);
    if(iso_date>= new Date() && iso_date<= new Date(new Date().setDate(new 
     Date().getDate()+4))){
        printjson(doc);
    }
})
```

I am unable to remove `_id` field using `printjson()` in MongoDB. I am printing fields based on a particular condition which I have handled using JavaScript. While printing using `printjson()`, I can't remove `_id` field. Is there a way to remove `_id` while printing using `printjson()`?

Comment: Can you show us your code?

Comment: @Alicia added the code, now the line printjson(doc) prints the document properly, but i want to remove the _id field that is generated by mongoDb shell itself.

Comment: Just delete the `_id` prop from the `doc` object before printing:
`delete doc._id; printjson(doc);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use [projection](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/) to avoid returning _id in db results :

```
db.events.find(
  {starts_at: {$gte: Date.now(), $lte: new Date().setDate(4)}},
  {_id:0} 
)
.forEach(function(doc)
{
    printjson(doc);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As JME pointed out in the comment to your question, you can delete the _id field before printing the document. On the other hand, the comparison of dates could be something simpler and, more importantly, you should do it in the query to treat only the documents you want instead of looping through all the documents in the database, so I think your code could look like this:

```
db.events.find({starts_at: {$gte: Date.now(), $lte: new Date().setDate(4)}}).forEach(function(doc)
{
    delete doc._id;
    printjson(doc);
});
```